# Need Solution to reduce object creation, used spring - but have a problem , method explained in detail

Tags: java

I am using spring to reduce new objects creation, for the number of resultset available, I will create a row object inside and add the row object in a rowset object, which maintains a list of rows.

My code goes like this.

```
 while(rs.next()) {
   Row r = new Row();
   //Logic
   rowset.addRow(r);
}
```

My rs will have atleast a minimum of 3000 rows, so there will be a 3000 row object injected, so to avoid it, I used spring injection like

```
 while(rs.next()) {
    Row r = (Row)getApplicationContext().getBean("row");
   //Logic
   rowset.addRow(r);
}
```

but the problem here is when the second row object is added to the rowset, the first row object's values are overriden with second row object and when last row is added , all the 1 to last-1 row objects values are updated as last row object values.

This is my rowset calss

```
public class RowSet {
 private ArrayList m_alRow;
 public RowSet() {
 m_alRow = new ArrayList();
 }
 public void addRow(Row row) {
 m_alRow.add(row);
 }
}
```

I need a solution , such that the new row object creation is avoided inside the while loop with the same logic involved.

Answer (score 3):

Spring injection is not your answer here.  You aren't avoiding any of the problems with keeping 3,000 rows in memory.  You're chewing up the same RAM whether you call "new" to create them or the bean factory creates.

I'd question why you need all 3,000 rows in memory at once.  I can see where might ask for them in smaller bites, or perhaps ask the database server to crunch them into a useable piece of data instead of hauling all that data to the middle tier.

I'd rethink your design.

A RowSet might be a fine abstraction for a persistence tier, but I don't see any business objects here.  What are you doing with that data?  How is it ultimately consumed?

You should follow Google's example if you simply send it to a user interface for display.  Google might get back millions of responses to your query, but it only shows them to you 25 at a time, with the best answers coming up first.  They're betting that you won't need the rest of those million results if the first one meets your need.  Maybe you need to try that for your problem, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, this is the old code and there is an imposition that the logic should not be changed, and this data, we retrieve to finally write to the outputstream in excel format, we have tried wid other solutions like POI and other Excel API, but they all consume more memory than this. I thought of Using spring because, the object lifecycle will be taken care of spring internally and I saw the memory is cleaned up , when some 1000 rows are fetched, this did not happen wid direct 'new'.

Comment: And 3000 rows is minimum count, it exceeds 10,000 sometimes. yes we are thinking to have a redesign , like buffering data etc, but as of now, i want to take of these new objects in while loop.

Comment: Buffering isn't going to help you.

Comment: Buffering , I meant as sending the no of rows to be retrieved from DB , but anyways if the user is always in need of >1000 rows then still the pandora's box is open...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for 3000 records with 3000 different values then 3000 objects are the only way to go. If you are retrieving data only from one column then this could be mitigated by adding them to a list (Which internally autoboxes to objects for primitives so it also ends up with 3000 objects). Why not try ORM tools like Hibernate and not worry about too much data wiring?

Comment: I don't see how Hibernate will help here.  There's no business object in sight.  The "O" in ORM stands for object.  It needs to be more specifically tailored to the problem at hand than a generic RowSet.

Comment: I assumed that the example was a mask of a real implementation instead of a classroom one. I did not see how the RowSet is used in the service side. Hence that assumption

Comment: Nope, using hibernate/DB store proc call, will not make any difference here. our ultimate aim is to write data to excel with minimum objects in heap, and our code is optimized than other excel APIs - but the problem is sometimes if there is 10,000 data retrieved, then as per the Row r = new Row (), there will be 10,000 Row objects in heap.

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring returns a single instance.  So you are simply fetching the same row over and over.  This is why the values are overwritten, you only have 1 instance of Row.  If your goal was to create less objects, you have achieved it, of course your logic has suffered for it  8-)

As was mentioned, if you are going to store 3000 unique values, you will need 3000 objects, its that simple.  Even what you were attempting to do with Spring was still going to create those objects, only you were making a very simple new statement into an obfuscated call to Spring to do the new for you.

This is a horrible misuse of Spring, it is meant for dependency injection not to simply replace **new**, you made a very simple and clear statement complex by doing it this way.

PS - You can create a new object each time with Spring, but you have to configure it to do so.  I won't elaborate, since this is not the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks Robin, yes I can understand, but some how I dont want to make the New Row objects inside the while loop. I can understand spring is not for object instantiation, but for injection (dependency), why i have used spring approach because , I could see the heap size reducing when I used Spring , but with New Row - i could see the heap size always on ++ coordinates.

Comment: And I assumed , spring framework internally does some cleanup, so that the heap size curve is coming down.

Comment: We can use a bean facrory and can make the bean as prototype, so that , each call will give a new instantiation of the object, yes but thats not the need of the hour.